# malloc issue with a OpenCL code - Huge size of mach_vm_map on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, malloc, out-of-memory, opencl

I have an issue about the porting of a OpenCL code from Linux (where it's working) to Mac OS X 10.9.5.

At the part of this code where I am using malloc, when I launch executable, I get the following error :

```
OpenCLSimu(13400,0x7fff7da7c310) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1556840295209897984) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

As you can see, the requested memory is huge : 1556840295209897984 bytes, so the allocation fails.

Here's the routine for allocation part (NumBodies is 30720 in my case) :

```
int OpenCLSimu::setup()
{
  // Make sure numParticles is multiple of group size
  numBodies = (cl_int)(((size_t) getNumParticles() 
        < groupSize) ? groupSize : getNumParticles());

  initPos = (cl_double*) malloc(numBodies * sizeof(cl_double4));
  CHECK_ALLOCATION(initPos, "Failed to allocate host memory. (initPos)");

  initVel = (cl_double*) malloc(numBodies * sizeof(cl_double4));
  CHECK_ALLOCATION(initVel, "Failed to allocate host memory. (initVel)");

  pos = (cl_double*) malloc(numBodies * sizeof(cl_double4));
  CHECK_ALLOCATION(pos, "Failed to allocate host memory. (pos)");

  vel= (cl_double*) malloc(numBodies * sizeof(cl_double4));
  CHECK_ALLOCATION(vel, "Failed to allocate host memory. (vel)");

  return NBODY_SUCCESS;
}
```

I don't know if there is a relation but I've found out on https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8043507 (with Java language) that on OS X, we have to specify uint32_t type for size.

Maybe this issue comes from the clang compiler that I use for compilation.

```
CC            = /usr/bin/clang
CXX           = /usr/bin/clang++
DEFINES       = -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED
CFLAGS        = -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
```

I tried also to set numBodies to 3072 in order to see the huge size of `mach_vm_map` and I get :

malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=868306322687266816) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

I noticed these sizes are always changing for different executions.

Finally, I had for the Linux version for `pos` and `vel` arrays into the above routine :

```
pos = (cl_double*)memalign(16, numBodies * sizeof(cl_double4));

vel = (cl_double*)memalign(16, numBodies * sizeof(cl_double4));
```

instead of malloc using :

```
  pos = (cl_double*) malloc(numBodies * sizeof(cl_double4));

  vel= (cl_double*) malloc(numBodies * sizeof(cl_double4));
```

I have seen that on OS X, the data were aligned by default on 16 byte boundary, that's why I replace `memalign` by `malloc` for MacOS version

If someone had a clue, this would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE :**

The error occurs between the "`cout << size of source =" << sourceSize << endl`" and the "`cout << "status =" << status << endl`", so it fails on the `clCreateProgramWithSource` method :

```
// create a CL program using the kernel source                                         
  const char *kernelName = "Simu_Kernels.cl";                                           
  FILE *fp = fopen(kernelName, "r");                                                     
  if (!fp) {                                                                             
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");                                         
    exit(1);                                                                             
  } 
  char *source = (char*)malloc(10000);                                                   
  int sourceSize = fread( source, 1, 10000, fp);                                         
  fclose(fp);                                                                            

  cout << "size of source =" << sourceSize << endl;                                      

  // Create a program from the kernel source                                             
  program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source, (const size_t *)&sourceSize, &status);
  //program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source, NULL, &status);

  cout << "status =" << status << endl;
  cout << "current_device =" << current_device<< endl;
```

At the execution, I get :

```
Selected Platform Vendor : Apple
Device 0 : Iris Pro Device ID is 0x1024500
Device 1 : GeForce GT 750M Device ID is 0x1022700
size of source =2026
OpenCLSimu(15802,0x7fff7da7c310) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=59606861803950080) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
status =-6
```

and `status = -6` corresponds to a `CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY`

I make you notice that I have 2 GPU units on my macbook (Iris Pro Device and GeForce GT 750M). I have the same error for both devices.

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried printing out the value of `numBodies` just before your `malloc` calls to make sure it really is what you think it is?

Comment: I have printed the value for numBodies before malloc and it is correct.

Comment: it seems that problem comes from conflicts between float numbers with comma separator and with dot separator. I have to check the locale used.

Comment: At what line exactly does it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create program as follows:

```
static char* Read_Source_File(
        const char  *filename,
        size_t      *file_len)
{
    long int
        size = 0,
        res  = 0;

    char *src = NULL;

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (!file)  return NULL;

    if (fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END))
    {
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    size = ftell(file);
    *file_len = size;
    if (size == 0)
    {
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    rewind(file);

    src = (char *)calloc(size + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (!src)
    {
        src = NULL;
        fclose(file);
        return src;
    }

    res = fread(src, 1, sizeof(char) * size, file);
    if (res != sizeof(char) * size)
    {
        fclose(file);
        free(src);

        return (char*)NULL;
    }

    src[size] = '\0'; /* NULL terminated */
    fclose(file);

    return src;
}

size_t file_len;
char *source = Read_Source_File("path_to_kernel.cl", &file_len);
if(source){
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&src_file, NULL, &status);
}
```